# Format Telephone Number in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a telephone numbers as follows:

```
Telephone No

03-58164661
03-5816-7791
03-6433-4661
03-45673661
22-345-1234
564-33-6789
```

I need to separate only the eight digit number with '-'

```
03-5816-4661
03-5816-7791
03-6433-4661
03-4567-3661
22-345-1234
564-33-6789
```

Comment: Are all telephone numbers the same digit count?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, STUFF will add the hyphen for you, and the CASE statement ensure that only those without the hyphen are affected

```
Declare @s varchar(50) = '03-5816-4661'
Select 
CASE WHEN RIGHT(@s,5) !='-' then 
Stuff(@s, Len(@s)-3, 0, '-')
else @S
end as [Tele]
```

Comment: I have updated my question if there is eight digit number after '-' 22-34345678 then I need to place the '-', like say if I have 22-345-33456 I should not do anything and just I should leave it.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming that all numbers will be of the same length as you have shown in samples.

```
declare @num varchar(50)='0358164661'

select reverse(stuff(reverse(stuff(@num,3,case when CHARINDEX('-',@num,1)<>3 then 0 
else 1 end ,'-')),5,case when CHARINDEX('-',@num,4)<>8 then 0 else 1 end,'-'))
```

**Updated Answer working for all the mentioned scenarios.**

```
select case when CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING (@num,1,5),1)<>0 then SUBSTRING 
(@num,1,5)  else stuff(SUBSTRING (@num,1,5),3,0,'-') end
 +reverse(case when CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING (reverse(@num),1,len(@num)-5),1)<>0 
then SUBSTRING (reverse(@num),1,len(@num)-5)  
else stuff(SUBSTRING (reverse(@num),1,len(@num)-5),5,0,'-') end)
```

Comment: this is not working if we have already 2 separaters not need to do 22-333-45363, if we have only one separater '-' then followed by 8 digit code then we need to place the '-' in between 4 digits.

Comment: your script fails for : 22-345-56784 this number should not have any change. but your script displays 22-345-5-6784 is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
JobTout,
```

Small changes to your script works for me.

```
Declare @s varchar(50) = '03-58164661'
Select 
CASE WHEN LEN(@s) - LEN(REPLACE(@s,'-','')) = 1 then -- AND RIGHT(@s,5) !='-' then 
Stuff(@s, Len(@s)-3, 0, '-')
else @S
end as [Tele]
```

Comment: You can improve it slightly using this: SELECT case when col like '%-%-%' THEN col ELSE Stuff(col, Len(col)-3, 0, '-') END